# Attach data to running event loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I would like to attach some data to a currently running loop. This can be very useful in sharing secret keys, or reusing sessions. For example, something like

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def func1():
  loop=asyncio.get_running_loop()
  loop["client_session"] = aiohttp.ClientSession()

async def func2():
  loop=asyncio.get_running_loop()
  return await loop["client_session"].get("https://google.com")

async def main():
  await func1()
  return await func2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  asyncio.run(main())
```

My question is, would the above code work, is it reliable, or is there a better way?

I know that data can be attached to an `aiohttp.Application`, and so I'm wondering if the same can be done for general asyncio loops.

Comment: Interesting idea. But basically it would be a global variable. What is the benefit of annotating the loop compared to using a global variable?

Comment: Good question. I could think of two differences from a global variable:
1. Different loops can have different values for the variable. Unsure of what the use case would be here though.
2. It would be shareable across modules. If I'm not mistaken, adding a global variable to, say, `common.config`, and importing it in different modules will cause the variable to be a separate instance in each module. This is good enough to share immutable objects such as strings, but can't be used to share sessions, for example.

Comment: ^ I originally thought that you can't share global variable instances between modules, but that turned out to be wrong. Perhaps global variables is the way to go.